# Homeworld 2 map scripting with lua 4 unknown errors

Tags: lua-4.0

I am scripting maps for the game Homeworld 2, the original NOT remastered (since I don't have and can't get remastered).

Problem is, I'm getting an error in the script somewhere, which I'm pretty sure is a syntax error because it makes the game crash before the main menu (from experience other error types usually cause a crash at the time the map loads).

I have tried using codepad.org and checked out other similar sites, but they don't let you choose lua version 4 (which is what Homeworld 2 uses), so I can only assume they use lua 5, which means their utility is rather limited. Codepad said my code was good despite this.

I have skimmed the lua 4 documentation, but honestly I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Thus far, my programming experience is c++, and the little bit of lua I gleaned from example Homeworld 2 maps and my quick perusal of the documentation.

As near as I can tell the code should be good. I do recall hearing something ages ago that not all of lua was valid in Homeworld 2 and that Homeworld 2 had additional limits on what lua could do, though I haven't been able to find it again.

All my research in trying to solve this issue from searching the Homeworld end of things keeps bringing up the remastered stuff rather than the original homeworld 2 stuff, and remastered has changed things about some. Even then, I still haven't found any topics on the limits of lua scripting.

The script I made basically makes a random map of a randomly chosen style (i.e. the resources might be evenly distributed throughout the map, be concentrated in a big field, or come in clusters, or even a big ring.).

My first version of the map worked, but was messy and disorganized, so I rewrote the whole thing to be neater and easier to tweak (i.e. I moved many variables to the top so they can be easily found).

All the core code should in theory be the same, only with certain things moved around, and better commented.

I did put some of the code into functions and called the functions, but I can't find anything that says I did it wrong.

So what I need is something that can either check lua 4 code for errors (the ones that can be found without running it anyway), or something that rather clearly shows how lua 4 did things different from lua 5. Of course, if anyone knows anything about Homeworld 2 specific limitations, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience with C++, it shouldn't be a problem for you to compile a standalone version of [Lua 4.0.1](https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-4.0.1.tar.gz) (it's very easy, and the codebase is highly standards compliant, compared to typical C/C++ projects). This would certainly let you at least check for syntax errors (i.e. "errors which can be found without running it").